# Trying to get to array options within an array

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, uitableview

I'm got an `NSArray` with has 6 `ACustomObject`'s inside it. Each `ACustomObject` has an `NSArray` that contains a number of `BCustomObject`'s inside that array.

The reason for this was to keep data together. So that each `ACustomObject` has a `BCustomObject` property that has a list of options.

Now I wanted to display this data in a UITableViewController in a `grouped style` so that each section would be `ACustomObject`'s title and the rows would be the amount of `BCustomObjects` that belonged to the `ACustomObject`

So it would look like this in each section of the UITableView

**Section One**

- Section Title: 
  **ACustomObject -> Title**
- `BCustonObject.property`
- `BCustonObject.property`
- `BCustonObject.property`
- `BCustonObject.property`

**Section TWO**

- Section Title: 
  **ACustomObject -> Some Title**
- `BCustonObject.property`
- `BCustonObject.property`
- `BCustonObject.property`
- `BCustonObject.property`

..and so on..

So I attempted to iterated through the `arrayMain` that contains both `NSObjects`

To get the `ACustonObjects` into a separate array (For the section count) I did this:

```
for (ACustomObject *customObject in self.arrayMain){

        [self.aCustomObjectArray addObject: customObject];
    }
```

So this worked just fine.

However when I do this:

```
for (BCustomObject *customObject in self.arrayMain){

        [self.bCustomObjectArray addObject: customObject];
    }
```

The array: `self.bCustomObjectArray` has both `ACustomObjects` and arrays with `BCustomObjects` inside it.

Not sure how to split up the arrays correctly.

The main array that has all objects inside it looks like this:

ArrayOne: 
->`ACustomObject` 
     ->NSArray 
         ->BCustomObject

Comment: I'm assuming you're really using NSMutableArrays. For nested Arrays, it's just best to create the subarrays first, then add all the subarrays to the main array.  It looks like you're looping through the same set of objects, and in the first loop, you're calling them ACustomObjects and the second time you're calling them BCustomObjects, but they're the same objects each time.

Comment: You dont even need to make separate arrays for your sections/cells. You can directly access self.arrayMain in the delegate methods.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get `ACustomObject`s from `self.arrayMain`.

```
for (id object in self.arrayMain) {
    if([object isKindOfClass:[ACustomObject class]]) {
        [self.aCustomObjects addObject:object];
    }
}
```

Then the number of sections would be:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView {
    return [self.aCustomObjects count];
}
```

And number of rows for each particular section would be:

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
   ACustomObject *object = self.aCustomObjects[(NSUInteger)section];
   return [object.bCustomObjects count];
}
```

I assume that `object.bCustomObjects` is an array of `BCustomObject`'s in `ACustomObject`.

Comment: That's actually perfect. Works very well. I will dig more into how your code works as you made it much simpler than what I was trying.

Answer (score 2):

First, let's fix the error in your code: when you iterate `self.arrayMain`, you get `ACustomObject`s. To get `BCustomObject`s from them you need a nested loop:

```
for (ACustomObject *ownerOfBs in self.arrayMain) {
    for (BCustomObject *customObject in ownerOfBs.arrayOfBs) {
        [self.bCustomObjectArray addObject:customObject];
    }
}
```

Next, let's see if you can avoid "flattening" `BCustomObject`s: recall that the `UITableViewDataSource` delegate protocol has `tableView:numberOfRowsInSection:` method. In order to implement that method, all you need is grabbing the `count` of `arrayOfBs` in the corresponding section.

Then, you need to implement your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` method. In order to do that, grab the `indexPath.section` number, get `ACustomObject` at the section index from `self.arrayMain`, then grab the `BCustomObject` at `indexPath.row` index.

At this point you are done: you no longer need to flatten your `BCustomObject`, because the table view deals with it for you.

Comment: Thanks, this did what I needed. However, like you said - it flatterns the array and now the two objects are not paired up anymore. I'll try implementing your suggestion to fix this.

Comment: I would have marked this answer correct as technically it does answer the question and your advice was very helpful. However @Maciel Oczke solved the over all problem for me. However I'll vote this answer up as I can't mark two answers as correct. Thanks again!